# Convert PHP array to chart.js compatible data

Tags: php, arrays, chart.js

Am using [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) to display charts on my site. The working data attribute for chart.js is in this format

```
"data" => ['1', '2', '3']
```

I have my data currently in a PHP array

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )
```

However this is not working for my needs. How can I convert the PHP array into the same format as above?

I have tried

```
 json_encode($myArray)
```

and

```
implode($myArray)
```

without success.
Any suggestions?

Comment: "The working data attribute for chart.js is in this format `"data" => ['1', '2', '3'].`" <- I doubt it, that doesn't look like JS at all. Please share your current JS code (with hardcoded data).

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array with key "data" and another array as the value;

```
$myArray = ["data" => [1, 2, 3]];
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

Output

```
{"data":[1,2,3]}
```

Or put the values between quotes

```
$myArray = ["data" => ["1", "2", "3"]];
```

Output

```
{"data":["1","2","3"]}
```

Comment: No luck with either of these unfortunately, should be so simple? Any further suggestions?

Comment: I don't know how you feed the data to a chart. If I look at [this page](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/) there are 2 keys named `data`. Is your data structure correct and are you using the right key? Do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure completely understood the problem. But if you want to convert values of php array to a json you can do something like that:
`json_encode(array_values($myArray));`